# Deserializing to a collection object not working with Symfony serializer (possible Symfony bug?)

Tags: symfony, serialization

When I try to deserialize a collection object using Symfony serializer I always get an empty collection.

I have the following read only classes:

```php
final readonly class Order
{
    public function __construct(public Items $items) 
    {
    }
}

final readonly class Items
{
    /**
     * @var array<Item>
     */
    public array $items;

    public function __construct(Item ...$items)
    {
        $this->items = $items;
    }
}

final readonly class Item
{
    public function __construct(public string $code) 
    {
    }
}
```

The serializer is set up like this:

```php
$serializer = new Serializer(
    normalizers: [
        new ArrayDenormalizer(),
        new ObjectNormalizer(
            propertyTypeExtractor: new PropertyInfoExtractor(
                typeExtractors: [new PhpDocExtractor(), new ReflectionExtractor()],
            ),
        ),
    ],
    encoders: [
        new JsonEncoder()
    ]
);
```

After deserializing from json, the `$items` property of the `Order` object *is* an instance of `Items` but the `$items` array of `Items` remains empty:

```php
$json = json_encode([
    'items' => [
        ['code' => 'test-code-1'],
        ['code' => 'test-code-2'],
    ],
]);


$order = $serializer->deserialize($json, Order::class, 'json');

var_dump($order->items->items); 


Output:
array(0) { }
```

As a workaround I have removed the `Items` class and moved the items array to the `Order` object itself:

```php
final readonly class Order
{
    public function __construct(
        /** @var array<Item> */        
        public array $items
    ){
    }
}

final readonly class Item
{
    public function __construct(public string $code) 
    {
    }
}
```

This will produce the expected result:

```php
$order = $serializer->deserialize($json, Order::class, 'json');

var_dump($order->items); 

Output:
array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(Item)#1467 (1) { 
        ["code"]=> string(11) "test-code-1" 
    } 
    [1]=> object(Item)#1465 (1) { 
        ["code"]=> string(11) "test-code-2" 
    }
}
```

The downside of this approach is that I have to add docblocks telling the serializer that `$items` is an array containing `Item` objects.

I've tested this in a Symfony 5.4 and 6.3 project.
Am I missing something or is this a bug in the Serializer component?

Comment: the Items class is essentially an `array<Item>` which I suspect causes the problem. The ObjectSerializer (and Deserializer) only gets an array, and it sees that the property on Order should be an Items. So even if it tried to manage to create an Items object, it would then have to map the array's keys (0 and 1 in your case) to properties of the Items class, which doesn't work. However, I wonder if you could make Items extend for example a Collection and add a docblock `@extends Collection<Item>` to it. (doctrine/collections should work)

Comment: what would also work is having a `setItems(array $items)` function on `Order` that just constructs an Items object.

Comment: I have tried adding a setter but this undermines the immutability (readonly) of the class. I will try to convert the array to a Doctrine collection, this should work!

Answer (score 0):

If it could help, here what I'm using:

```php
$serializer = new Serializer([
    new ProblemNormalizer(),
    new JsonSerializableNormalizer(),
    new ConstraintViolationListNormalizer(),
    new DateTimeNormalizer($context),
    new DateTimeZoneNormalizer(),
    new DateIntervalNormalizer(),
    new DataUriNormalizer(),
    new ArrayDenormalizer(),
    new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor()),
], [
    new JsonEncoder(),
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try this later on. For now I will settle on @jakumi's suggestion by using collection objects.